# Lock screen asks for password on no-password account

Tags: password, lightdm, lock-screen

The Ubuntu lock screen always asks for a password even when the account does not have password.
In my opinion, it should be exactly like the login screen: a button "connect >" for accounts that don't have a password.

As a workaround, I can "Change account" and re-select my account to unlock the screen.

I know that manually locking a non-password account is useless, but the default setting is for the screen to lock automatically.

Comment: This seems to be a legitimate bug in lightdm, the program that manages the Ubuntu lock screen on 14.04 and later. Please see further discussion on this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/573161/cannot-unlock-session-if-user-has-no-password

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot unlock session if user has no password](http://askubuntu.com/questions/573161/cannot-unlock-session-if-user-has-no-password)